# How to recode a variable with backslash and double quotes into NA?

Tags: r, dplyr, recode

A dataset I am working with has NA values as `\\"\\"` I need to recode this into NA in order to collapse some variables but I have not been able to escape the double quotes successfully. I have tried treating the variable as characters and used `mutate(x = case when(X == ' \\"\\" ' ~ NA))` as well as `mutate(x = fct_recode(x, NULL = '\\"\\"' )` with no luck as it recognizes all values as `NA's` once I do both approaches. The values I am interested in keeping both start with " and end with " but have numerical values in between.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: `x <- c(1, "\"\"", 2, "\"\"", 3);x[x %in% "\"\""] <- NA;x`?  Where's exactly your problem?

Comment: the dataset has 50k observations and multiple variables where \"\" needs to be replaced with NA, is there a way to do this replacement for the entire dataset at once?

Comment: Try `lapply(dat, function(x) {x[x %in% "\"\""] <- NA;x})`.

Comment: is x in function(x) the variable name? if so it does not seem to be working

Comment: No, it's just anonymous `x`, just replace `dat` with your data frame name. BTW you probably would get more enthusiastic answers when you put in some effort and make a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610).

Comment: thanks a lot! I'll be sure to do so in the future, first day in stack overflow. Have a good day!